# JQuery Ajax Success is never reached

Tags: jquery

I have an AJAX statement like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "DBDeleteList.php",
            data: {listID: listID},
            success: function(html){
                /* Succesfully Updated DB */
                alert( 'Saved!' );
                $(this).parents('li').remove();
                $('#sortableLoader').load('index.php #sortableMenu');
            }
});
```

It works fine and fires the PHP file and everything, the Database modifications work correctly.

The only problem is that the "success:" part doesn't ever fire, even if it is successfull.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: can you use firebug to see what status code is returned from your php page?

Comment: Did you try to see the console output in firebug?

Comment: verify that the response for the given url is a valid JSON response.

Comment: What exactly does `$(this)` inside that ajax function call refer to ?

Comment: did you check to see if failure: fires?

Comment: Most likely you are not getting valid json. Add `error: function(x,y,z) { alert(z) }` and respond with what the error is. I expect "parseerror" which would confirm invalid json.

Comment: It is Valid JSON. Checked Console Return in Firebug, the return was a successful passing of the variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a return error you are not seeing.  You are posting properly to the php, but whatever you are returning back after your post, your ajax call doesnt like. Include something like this after your success function to debug:

```
error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        alert('Time out error.');
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
    } else {
        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
}
```

also I would use firebug to help see what is happening

Comment: Note that jqXHR.status is `0` in other cases as well. If I start an ajax request, and reloads the page, the started ajax request will be cancelled, returning a status of 0. 

You're better of using `navigator.onLine`, to check if the user is connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't understand what `$(this)` inside that ajax function call refers to, that is I understand what it refers to, but I doubt it has any parents ?

Why do you use the variable `html` for the returned data in the success handler when you're expecting json data.

Are you sure this is'nt a problem with malformed json causing a parse error ?

Try leaving out the datatype and see what it returns, and add an error handler:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DBDeleteList.php",
    data: { listID: listID },
}).done(function(html) {
     console.log(html);
}).fail(function(a,b,c) {
     console.log('error'+'-=-'+a+'-=-'+b+'-=-'+c);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a pointer to the element in question before the ajax call, otherwise the "$(this)" in your success refers to the xhr response. Make sure the response is the right content type (application/json).

```
var $el = $(this);
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "DBDeleteList.php",
        data: {listID: listID},
        dataType:"json",
        contentType : 'application/json',
        processData:false,
        success: function(html){
            /* Succesfully Updated DB */
            alert( 'Saved!' );
            $el.parents('li').remove();
            $('#sortableLoader').load('index.php #sortableMenu');
        }
});
```

Also verify that the response's json is valid. If either of these are not met, in most cases it will fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a typo. I had written `success` but `sucess`.